# How to sanely format conditionals in clrscode package?

Tags: indentation, algorithms

`clrscode` can produce some really nice-looking algorithm texts, but if you have nested conditionals, things start to look ugly.  `clrscode` has the peculiar preference that the `\Then` keyword at the end of an `\If` statement should go on a second line, indented.

Not only is this not very compact (needed for a paper in two-column format!), it runs counter to the convention in most mainstream programming languages. If you try to place the `\Then` at the end of the same line that the `\If` is on, the package often overprints the `\Then` on top of the conditional expression!

To be clear, you need to do this

```
\li \If $a = b$
\li   \Then foo
```

but I would really like to do

```
\li \If $a = b$ \Then foo
```

or

```
\li \If $a = b$ \Then
\li   foo
```

Furthermore, I would like to be able to line up `\Else` statements with the preceding `\If` (not the preceding `\Then`!), and this does not seem to be possible, either.

Any pointers?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid `clrscode` is not among the most widely used packages. Can you add a minimal example of a complete document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`clrscode`](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/) sets the algorithm inside a box (`lrbox`) of fixed with (using a `minipage` environment), and aligns the algorithm content using `tabbing`. The following updates `\Then` and `\Else` (and `\Until`) fits within your requirements (I think):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clrscode}% http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/
\begin{document}
\begin{codebox}
  \Procname{$\proc{Hash-Insert}(T,k)$}
  \li $i \gets 0$
  \li \Repeat
  \li   $j \gets h(k,i)$
  \li   \If $T[j] == \const{nil}$
  \li   \Then
          $T[j] \gets k$
  \li     \Return $j$
  \li   \Else
          $i \gets i+1$
        \End
  \li \Until $i == m$
  \li \Error ``hash table overflow''
\end{codebox}

% Updates to \Then and \Else
\renewcommand{\Then}{%
  \textbf{then}\stepcounter{indent} }
\renewcommand{\Else}{%
  \kill\addtocounter{indent}{-1}%
  \liprint\textbf{else}\>\>\stepcounter{indent}}
\renewcommand{\Until}{%
  \addtocounter{indent}{-1}%
  \kill\liprint\textbf{until} }

\begin{codebox}
  \Procname{$\proc{Hash-Insert}(T,k)$}
  \li $i \gets 0$
  \li \Repeat
  \li   $j \gets h(k,i)$
  \li   \If $T[j] == \const{nil}$ \Then
  \li     $T[j] \gets k$
  \li     \Return $j$
  \li   \Else $i \gets i+1$
        \End
  \li \Until $i == m$
  \li \Error ``hash table overflow''
\end{codebox}

\end{document}
```

Of course, more corrections in terms of the input is possible, depending on some clarification.

Also, [`clrscode3e`](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/clrscode3e.sty) exists which is a "third edition" update of [`clrscode`](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/clrscode.sty) (used in editions 1 and 2 of *Introduction to Algorithms*). This update, as stated in the [`clrscode3e` documentation](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/clrscode3e.pdf) contains a number of user-feedback improvements. Specific to the `\If`-`\Then` clauses (section **Typesetting if statements**, p 8):

> In the first two editions of the book, the keyword **then** appeared in
>   pseudocode, but — again mindful of requests from our readers to make our pseudocode more like C, C++,
>   and Java — we eliminated the keyword **then** in the third edition. The `\Then` command remains, however, in
>   order to indent the code that runs when the test in the **if** clause evaluates to *TRUE*.

From `clrscode.sty`, here's the formal definition of all the keywords:

```
% All of our favorite keywords.
\newcommand{\For}{\textbf{for} }
\newcommand{\To}{\textbf{to} }
\newcommand{\By}{\textbf{by} }
\newcommand{\Downto}{\textbf{downto} }
\newcommand{\While}{\textbf{while} }
\newcommand{\Repeat}{\textbf{repeat}\>\>\addtocounter{indent}{1}}
\newcommand{\Until}{\kill\addtocounter{indent}{-1}\liprint\>\>\textbf{until}\hspace*{-0.7em}\'}
\newcommand{\If}{\textbf{if} }
\newcommand{\Then}{\>\textbf{then}\>\addtocounter{indent}{1}}
\newcommand{\Else}{\kill\addtocounter{indent}{-1}\liprint\>\textbf{else}\>\addtocounter{indent}{1}}
\newcommand{\End}{\addtocounter{indent}{-1}}
\newcommand{\ElseIf}{\kill\addtocounter{indent}{-1}\liprint\textbf{elseif} }
\newcommand{\ElseNoIf}{\kill\addtocounter{indent}{-1}\liprint\textbf{else} \addtocounter{indent}{1}}
\newcommand{\Do}{\>\>\textbf{do}\hspace*{-0.7em}\'\addtocounter{indent}{1}}
\newcommand{\Return}{\textbf{return} }
\newcommand{\Comment}{$\hspace*{-0.075em}\rhd$ }
\newcommand{\RComment}{\`\Comment}
\newcommand{\Goto}{\textbf{goto} }
\newcommand{\Error}{\textbf{error} } % optionally followed by string argument
```

Comment: Great answer! The pointer to clrscode3e was also very helpful. Thanks!